# How to hide a section and show another section in one click in elementor?

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to hide a section and show another section in one click.... is there any way to do that in elementor.

I searched on google but I get the result that only hide a  section and show it again on another click.
But I want to hide a section and show a hidden section in one click....

please, help me with the solution.
thank you.

Comment: You probably need to write some JavaScript/jQuery for that

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure to set a classname/id for each of your sections and also for your button.
   eg. let's say i have set `.sc1` and `.sc2` for sections and `.btn` for the button.
2. drag and drop HTML widget to your header template or the page/template you want the results in.
3. copy the following javascript code to your html, make sure to put it between script tag:

```js
var btn = document.querySelector('.btn');
    var sc1 = document.querySelector('.sc1');
    var sc2 = document.querySelector('.sc2');
    btn.addEventListener("click", function() {
    if (sc1.style.display === "none") {
    sc1.style.display = "block";
    sc2.style.display = "none";
    } else {
    sc1.style.display = "none";
    sc2.style.display = "block";
    }
    });
```

```css
.sc1, .sc2 {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
.sc1 {
  background: #000;
  display: block;
}
.sc2 {
  background: #e2062c;
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="sc1"></div>
  <div class="sc2"></div>
</div>
<button class="btn">click</button>
```